# How to create variable across entire java class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a method that asks for the user's name, then returns it. Now I want to access the user's name in another method, but when I print the user's name it says "null". I don't understand, I defined the variable, but how can I give it access across the entire class?

```
public static String userName() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Hello! Welcome to The Game. Whats your name? ");
        String userName = input.next();

        return userName;
}
```

This is the method where I try to access the userName variable but am given "null"

```
public static void homeMethod() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello " + userName + "! What would you like to do? (Type LIST for options)");
        String userGameChoice = input.nextLine();
}
```

Calling the userName() method inside the homeMethod() i am given the same error.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the variable in the class.

Comment: You need to call the method.

Comment: Thanks! I already had it there but realized I created a new variable in the userName() method, so I had two userName variables.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create userName variable outside of the method.

This is what I had:

```
public class MainGameClass {
    public static String userName;

    public static String userName() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Hello! Welcome to The Game. Whats your name? ");
    String userName = input.next();

    return userName;
    }

    public static void homeMethod() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("What would you like to do " + userName + "? (Type LIST for options)");
    String userGameChoice = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Output when calling homeMethod():

What would you like to do null? (Type LIST for options)

Solution:

```
public class MainGameClass {
    public static String userName;

    public static String userName() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Hello! Welcome to The Game. Whats your name? ");
    String userName = input.next();

    return userName;
    }

    public static void homeMethod() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("What would you like to do " + userName + "? (Type LIST for options)");
    userGameChoice = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Output when calling homeMethod():

What would you like to do (userName)? (Type LIST for options)

Explanation:

I correctly defined the userName variable in the class, however, in the userName() method, I created a new variable under the same name. Therefore not returning the answer to the userName variable.

Comment: this answer would be better if you have provided some code to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Either declare *userName* variable outside the method, in the class itself or call *userName* method in your *homeMethod* like this:

```
public static void homeMethod() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello " + userName() + "! What would you like to do? (Type LIST for options)");
    String userGameChoice = input.nextLine();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to put userName out of the method like this:

```
System.out.print("Hello! Welcome to The Game. Whats your name? ");
String userName = input.next()

public static String userName() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    return userName;
}
```